# Git files consistent with another project

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitignore

I am building on a project already present publically. I've only changed files on this project and added no new files. This project on Github is built after running the following commands,

```
cmake ../project -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path
make install
```

The project (before build) does not have any make files, but only source code (c++,lex,yacc,etc.), README, and CMakeLists.txt in many directories. Running these two commands increases the size of the project significantly by adding many make files, object files, packages, and binaries. This makes uploading to version control very costly.

I cannot track all the types of files because of the size of the project, so making a complicated gitignore is hard. I've also changed a lot of files over the course of time, so copying the changed ones to fresh cloned project and uploading would also be hard.

Since I am not adding any files and only modifying files already present in the main project (source code), can someone suggest an automated way of making a gitignore that makes the files that I upload exactly consistent with the ones in the main project without adding anything extra. Any other method would also be highly appreciated.